Status code http 500 in .NET Core Minimal API, EF, SQLite. Works locally but doesn't work on Azure
I built a Minimal API using EF, Sqlite and C#. It works locally, but once I deploy it to Azure, I get a http 500 status code and a SQLite error that the table doesn't exist. I don't know if it doesn't do the migrations because it works locally, please help - any advice?
Do I have to configure something so it will run the migrations and create the database in the cloud? First time I deploy backend with EF, have done it without it.
I asked chatgpt :v and searched on google (found nothing), chat gpt said that I should verify the configuration, or I don't have the table or the migrations is not well configured.

Have you also deployed the Sqlite to the Azure?  Also you need check the connection string to make sure the sqlite's file path is right inside the Azure.

Did you run migrations manually during development, using the dotnet ef tools? If so, you might have to run your database migrations on runtime, so the database schema is always up to date.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime
